# Python supports global scope of variable but Php doesn't supports global scope variables inside a function without using the global keyword?

Tags: php, scope, global-variables

```
<?php
   $a ="helllo welcome to php! ....:)"; 
   function msg(){ 
       /* global $a; */
       echo $a;
   } 
   msg();
?>
```

> Global variable $a is not accessible inside the function msg() but when i use global $a
> then it is accessible, i want to know that it is accessible or not
> without using global keyword inside or outside the function for the
> particular variable

[image: Output]

[image: Code]

✔ In python, it's accessible even without using the global keyword ✔

[image: But it is supported in python even without using global keyword ==> see the output at the right]

Comment: You are correct. Either pass the variables as arguments to the function or use the `global` keyword to allow them into scope of the function

Comment: Don't do that. Functions can accept parameters!

Comment: ok @ProfessorAbronsius it means that php doesn't supports global scope variables without using global keyword

Comment: @ibra i want to call $a variable without passing it inside the function

Comment: php doesn't supports global scope of variable without using global keyword

Comment: There is no logic here. if variables were accessible without the global keyword, what would be the reason to have this keyword at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense see the last image updated with the python code where the variable a is accessible inside the function msg() even without using the global keyword ....... :) :) :)

Comment: @Your In Python, `global` is only needed if you want to *assign* to the variable from within the function, but it’s readable without it. But PHP isn’t Python…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why did you commented `global $a` ?

```
<?php
   $a ="helllo welcome to php! ....:)"; 
   function msg(){ 
       global $a;
       echo $a;
   } 
   msg();
?>
```

Comment: actually I know this

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check for the variable's availability then your can use `isset($a)`.

I'm going to be honest and say that you shouldn't do that though. It doesn't make sense in any way.

The functions scope doesn't change and suddenly allow for the `$a` to be available. You should either use the `global` keyword, or pass the variable as an argument to the function.